# How do I re-enable the touchscreen on my iPhone after I've disabled it?

Tags: iphone, touchscreen

I have mistakenly disabled the touch screen of my iPhone 4S and now I cannot re-enable it.

Is there some method I can use to re-enable the touch screen on my device?

Comment: You didn't say *how* you disabled the touchscreen. Can't be done without jailbreaking. Pretty hard to answer this question without knowing that.

Comment: @ghoppe Actually you can disable it without a jailbreak by starting Guided Access.

Comment: actually you can restart your device and all will be well

Answer (score 5):

I can only assume you disabled touch input by starting Guided Access. To leave Guided Access, quickly push the Home button 3 times in a row. You will be prompted for your passcode, after which you can turn off Guided Access by pushing the End button.

More info on Guided Access in [this support article](http://support.apple.com/kb/HT5509?viewlocale=en_US&locale=en_US).

Answer (score 3):

Try the following methods:

1. Try the Siri command "Enable the touchscreen."

   1. Hold down your Home button until you hear the tone associated with Siri.
   2. Clearly speak "Enable the touchscreen" into the microphone.
2. Clean the screen with a clean, lint-free cloth. Take off your gloves, and wash your hands with warm water and soap. Dry your hands. Try again.
3. Remove a screen protector, if you have one. Try again.
4. Fully power down your iPhone:

   1. Hold down the power button and the Home button for 10 seconds.
   2. The iPhone should reset. Try again.
5. Restore your iPhone through iTunes.

I doubt step 1 will work, but if you've enabled some crazy jailbreak, you never know.

Comment: +1: The original question is vague enough that I dont know if it deserves an answer, or is capable of being answered. However, I salute this effort at cataloging everything that could disable a touchscreen in a theoretically reversible way.

Comment: Surely even on a jailbroken iPhone, tip number one does not make any sense.

Comment: With MyAssistant or some other Siri tweak, combined with another specific lockscreen tweak, I could see tip 1 working. That said, your Guided Access tip is much more likely to fix the issue.

Answer (score 0):

i can tell you this mutch if you have been messing around with JB, turn off your device, hold both buttons if you will, and then wile rebooting, press and hold volume up! and go and remove your stupid jb tweak that messed everthing up :)

Answer (score -1):

it really works to power off your phone by holding the home and off button  for 10 seconda then doing the same for turning it back on good luck it worked for me!